# Json extract of ['a','b','c']

Tags: mysql, json

My json is of the format ["a","b","c"]. I want to write a sql query such that

```
select *
from mytable
where a_column in json_extract["a","b","c"]
```

This logic does not work, because json_extract needs a path.

Is there any work around for this in mysql 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS('["a","b","c"]', JSON_QUOTE(a_column));
```

I assume that the column `a_column` is a string-type column which contains a value like `'a'`.